# Possible to turn an ifarme's parent's filename into a PHP Variable?

Tags: php

Is it possible to pass the filename of an iframe's parent to a PHP variable?
I am trying to dynamically generate an iframe that contains information that depends on the parent's filename. The iframe will be placed into multiple pages and it will be generate info based on what page it is in.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a query-string parameter to the `<iframe>`'s URL.

Comment: How would I be able to pass the parent's filename to the <iframe>'s URL? Is there a generic way similar to <iframe src="./child.php?FILENAME>  Might also be dumb, but how would you extrapolate the query-string parameter into a PHP variable?

Comment: @Anonyn: That part after the ? is called query string or query info part, see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php as well.

Comment: Yea, I referenced it. Totally forgot about superglobals. The problem I'm having is placing the document's filename into the query-string parameter. I can't hardcode it in. I need a solution that would run like <iframe src="./child.php?FILENAME> where FILENAME would be the filename of the current page (i.e. test.htm)